# Loading XML data from Talend to DB2

Tags: xml, etl, data-warehouse, talend

I know it is possible to load XML data from any database to Talend. But is there a way of writing XML data to a table in DB2 from Talend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talend has a variety of components to load data from XML to DB2. if you have XNL as source and DB2 as destination then you can parse XML and DB2 output using below list of components.

[tDB2Output](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/7.25+tDB2Output)

[tFileInputMSXML](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/13.19+tFileInputMSXML)

refer above link for more details, if you have specific scenario then we can help you in better way.

Answer (score 1):

There's an XML DB datatype for the DB2 output component but I don't have a DB2 licence to test the actual loading for you.

I have managed to load some data into a SQL Server database though but this requires creating a table with an XML datatype and then sending the data as a varchar as the SQL Server component doesn't actually have an XML datatype. This seems to load fine and works as expected so I would have thought that the tDB2Output component should work even better.